# CSS - Changing padding based on screen width with respect to specified max and min values

Tags: css, screen, padding

I want to set a padding value based on screen width with respect to specified intervals.

For example; Let's say there is a div. If the screen width is `1000px`, then i want to set `padding-right:30px` to the div. If the screen width is `700px`, then the padding value will be `padding-right:15px`. If the screen width is something between `1000px` and `700px` then the padding value must change proportionally.

How do i do that using **pure css** ?

Comment: please define 'proportionally' ?

Comment: If the screen size is let's say `990px`, then padding value equals `29px`. And If the screen is `980px` then maybe  `28.50`px. All the way down until `15px` for `700px`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is the solution:

```
@media (max-width:1000px) and (min-width:700px) {
    padding-right: calc(15px + (100vw - 700px) * (15 - 30) / (700 -  1000));
};
```

Just play with the numbers and you get the desired outcome with this pattern.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bz378x1j/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries combined with viewport-percentage lengths.

```
@media screen and (width: 1000px), screen and (width: 700px) {
    div {
        padding-right: 30px; 
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    div {
        padding-right: 10vw; /* Corresponds to 10% of the viewport width */
    }
}
```

More info on Media Queries here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

> **vw**
>   Equal to 1% of the width of the viewport's initial containing block.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: This way, i can't scale between 30px to 15px. As you mentioned, the value you get from this is x% of the screen width.